# Can I know what : does in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is the line of code I am trying to understand.

```
    var UIController = (function(){

       var domItems = {

          questInsertBtn: document.getElementById('question-insert-btn')

       };

   return{
      getDomItems: domItems
   }
})();
```

Is the above line the same as

```
 questInsertBtn =  document.getElementById('question-insert-btn');
```

Comment: The first line of code doesn't make sense by itself. The first line is setting up a key-value pair relationship in an object, whereas the second is just setting the variable `quesInsertBtn` equal to the element

Comment: May be your first line code is example of ternary operator.

Comment: Please post more context around the first line of code, so we can have an idea of what's going on there.

Answer (score 1):

They do very different things.

In common: They both attempt to resolve the expression `document.getElementById('question-insert-btn')`. That expression requests a call to a function, `document.getElementById`, and the expression resolves to the value returned from calling that function.

In this case, that function is called with one argument, the text string `'question-insert-btn'`.

[The `document.getElementById` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) finds (in the current HTML document) the HTML element whose `id` attribute matches that argument, and returns that element. So that's what will be stored in the `questInsertBtn` variable.

---

The first line of code you show:

> questInsertBtn: document.getElementById('question-insert-btn');

is very likely not a complete statement, and you'll get an error if you try to have that as a statement.

You might see a line like that as *part of* a statement, though. Please show the whole statement so we can know what that line is part of.

---

The second line:

> questInsertBtn =  document.getElementById('question-insert-btn');

if that's a single statement, constitutes an [assignment statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators). It assigns to a variable named `questInsertBtn` the value from the expression on the right side after the `=`. See above for how that expression is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not same. In the first case `questInsertBtn` is a key to an object and `document.getElementById('question-insert-btn');` value of that key. But standalone 
`questInsertBtn: document.getElementById('question-insert-btn');` does not make any sense

In second case `questInsertBtn` seems to be a variable & `document.getElementById('question-insert-btn');` is the value assigned to that variable

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain your code the best I can.
First, you have a variable (`UIController`) that will store the value returned by a [self-invoking](https://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/) function:

```
var UIController = (function()
{
    ...
})();
```

Second, the **returned value** of the `self-invoking` function will be an object with an unique `key` named `getDomItems` and **some value**. That **some value** will be an object composed by the `key` named `questInsertBtn` and his value, actually, the result of the method `getElementById('question-insert-btn')`:

```
...
var domItems = {questInsertBtn: document.getElementById('question-insert-btn')};    
return {getDomItems: domItems};
...
```

In sumary, all that code does is initialize the variable `UIController` with an object that will have this structure:

```
var UIController = {
  "getDomItems": {
    "questInsertBtn": value
  }
}
```

Where `value` is the result of the function `getElementById('question-insert-btn')`. You can check it by yourself on the next example, maybe the debugging from the `console.log()` will help better than my explanation:

```js
var UIController = (function()
{
    var domItems = {questInsertBtn: document.getElementById('question-insert-btn')};
    console.log("domItems: ", domItems);
    return {getDomItems: domItems};
})();

console.log("UIController: ", UIController);
```

```html
<button id="question-insert-btn"></button>
```